# How can I get ip address of mobile device (client) in (Node)?

Tags: node.js, react-native, ip-address

I have a mobile app (react native) and my backend is with node (express). I am running the app/my client on a real device (expo go). I am trying to get the ip address of my device. I tried:

`req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.connection.remoteAddress`

gives me the IPv6 address of my phone, not the actual ip address.

also tried:

```
   console.log(req.socket.localAddress)
   console.log(req.socket.remoteAddress);
   console.log(req.ip);
```

the first 2 return to me :1 which is the localhost ip as I understand.

Why am I getting the localhost if its suppose to give me the ip of the client, not the backend?

The third (req.ip), also gives me the IPv6 address of my phone, not the actual ip address. Why?

I am trying to add rate limit for each user which depends on me getting different ip addresses from mobiles devices (not the network router but device ip address). How can I do it?

Comment: You can try passing the IP of the device in header of the request. Also are you using emulator for development?

Comment: no im using a real device (expo go)

Comment: Maybe try this https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/network/

Comment: yes it does give me the actual ip address, i just tried to get it inside my backend and not having to send it